# Transferring tables with an "insert from location" statement in Sybase IQ is very slow

Tags: sql, sybase, data-transfer, sap-iq

I am trying to transfer several tables from a Sybase IQ database on one machine, to the same database on another machine (exact same schema and table layout etc).

To do this I'm using an insert from location statement:

```
insert into <local table> location <other machine> select * from mytablex
```

This works fine, but the problem is that it is desperately slow. I have a 1 gigabit connection between both machines, but the transfer rate is nowhere near that.

With a 1 gigabyte test file, it takes only 1 or 2 minutes to transfer it via ftp (just as a file, nothing to do with IQ). 
But I am only managing 100 gigabytes over 24 hours in IQ. That means that the transfer rate is more like 14 or 15 minutes for 1 gigabyte for the data going through Sybase IQ.

Is there any way I can speed this up?

I saw there is an option to change the packet size, but would that make a difference? Surely if the transfer is 7 times faster for a file the packet size can't be that much of a factor?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Can you specify which IQ version you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears from the documentation [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01773.1600/doc/html/san1288042668049.html) and [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01773.1600/doc/html/san1288042636189.html) that using `insert into` is a row by row operation, and not a bulk operation.  This could explain the performance issues that you are seeing.

You may want to look at the bulk loading [`LOAD TABLE`](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01773.1600/doc/html/san1288042646861.html) operation instead.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at this recommendation in the IQ best practices guide: [link](http://www.sybase.com/files/White_Papers/SybaseIQ15_best_practices_wp20110718.pdf) "While performing an INSERT…LOCATION operation, increase the communication packet size to 4K, if the data 
volume is large (the default is 512 bytes on most platforms): INSERT LOCATION PACKETSIZE 4096. Verify if the 
remote ASE (sp_configure default package size/ max package size ) and/or IQ (–p sever option) can handle this 
package size." That would suggest you can actually use it for large data transfers but not 100% sure..

Comment: I think an export and LOAD TABLE operation is the solution to this. Many thanks for the input - also to Hotel.

Answer (score 3):

If I recall correctly, IQ 15.x has known bugs where packetsize is effectively ignored for insert...location...select and the default 512 is always used.

The insert...location...select is a bulk tds operation typically, however we have found it to have limited value when working with gigabytes of data, and built a process to handle extract/Load Table that is significantly faster.

I know it's not the answer you want, but performance appears to degrade as the data size grows.  Some tables will actually never finish, if they are large enough.

Just a thought, you might want to specify the exact columns and wrap in an exec with dynamic sql.  Dynamic SQL is a no-no, but if you need the proc executable in dev/qa + prod environments, there really isn't another option.  I'm assuming this will be called in a controlled environment anyways, but here's what I mean:

```
declare @cmd varchar(2500), @location varchar(255)

set @location = 'SOMEDEVHOST.database_name'

set @cmd =    'insert localtablename (col1, col2, coln...) ' + 
              ''''+ trim(@location)+ '''' +
              ' { select col1, col2, coln... from remotetablename}'

select @cmd

execute(@cmd)
go
```

Comment: Thanks! This is actually quite useful. If the performance of the insert from location degrades it might not be possible to do it that way. Did you find the process you wrote much quicker? How much of a performance gain did you get?

Comment: Well, it's much faster and more reliable than not finishing at all.  I'd really say it depends on your requirements on whether you move to using LOAD TABLE.  In your case, it sounds like you're moving 100+GB of data...I'd recommend NOT doing that with the insert...location...select feature.   That's a lot of strain to put on the database from a transaction log standpoint.  I'm assuming you are batching the statements at some rowcount?  In any case I think this volume the correct approach is extracting to a file, and using the LOAD TABLE command on the destination.